# Ubuntu Installation Preference

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, hard-drive, ssd

I have decided to use Ubuntu, but I am a beginner. I have searched but there are lots of opinions about it, so I have decided to ask it here myself.

I have both Windows and Ubuntu and there are two disks on my laptop, 256 GB SSD and 1 TB HDD. I have partitioned my SSD into two, 206GB for Windows and 50GB for Ubuntu and I have installed Ubuntu into SSD. I have partitioned my HDD into two, first and the big one is for Windows applications and mass storage. The other partition is 150GB and I am planning to use it for Ubuntu programs. Now here is my questions.

1-Should I use a separate home partition? I understand that using separate home partition allows me to update Ubuntu without having problems with losing data and I am planning to do it. However, should I create this separate home partition into SSD or HDD? I am a little confused here. I will install my programs into HDD partition, so what is the difference having separate home folder in HDD vs SSD? If the answer is install it into SSD, should I also partition the existing SSD partition that I installed Ubuntu into it again?

2-In Windows, it is very easy to create partitions. I have handled the situation and created 150GB partition in HDD from Ubuntu in ext4 format. However, when I install a new software from Ubuntu Software for example, it does not ask me where to install it. Also, I have installed vim from terminal, it also did not ask me where to install it. Are all programs should be installed under home or something else? I am sensing it is a beginner question, I am already sorry.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

- Question 1:
  It's not really necessary, but a separate home partition can make life much more easier. Just make sure that it's an ext4 (or similar) formatted file system on your HDD. Performance should not be an issue in most day-to-day use cases.
- Question 2:
  If you're new linux, don't try to translate windows concepts to Ubuntu, etc. It'll cause much confusion and frustration. In Ubuntu (and other distributions), if you install software from the provided repositories (via `apt` or `dpkg` in this instance), you don't get to decide where the software will be installed to, since this is already determined in the package itself.